# How can I create a properly displayed view with multiple lines?

Tags: android, user-interface

I use a list for displaying a bunch of items with multiple texts. I want to have 2 TextView objects inside each item. My problem is that I can't adjust the properties to be able to stay proper when the user changes the text sizes (e.g.: when the user has eye problems, he might increase the system font size.) and it totally ruins my view.

The first text should be above the center of my layout and the second should be below the center, but they should not "coalesce" on different font sizes.  I thought about inserting a View inside the texts and format the texts to be placed relatively to the center (not visible) View, but it sounds a little bit hackish and ineffective. What's the best approach?

My current layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/upper_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/lower_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/upper_text"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/upper_text"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I know that I should get rid of the bottom margins and alignParent* stuff, but I have no idea what shall I do.

Comment: Post your code, and a picture of the problem case.  Unless you're doing something odd its unusual for this to be a problem.

Comment: Please try to provide some codes.

Answer (score 1):

Use recyclerview, it is very easy to update your data to layout .
[Try this link for that](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/)